# unrequire a file once it's been required in PHP

Tags: php, function, include, declaration, require

Suppose I do

```
require('lol.php');
```

whereby lol.php contains the following function declaration

```
function lolfunc(){

}
```

is it possible to "unrequire" lol.php such that I can then require another file

```
require('lol2.php');
```

whereby lol2.php contains a function with the same name previously declared in lol.php:

```
function lolfunc(){
  echo "this is lol2 biyotch";
}
```

and have lolfunc() be the one declared in lol2.php? eg if I call lolfunc() it'll echo "this is lol2 biyotch"??

Comment: No, it's not possible or reasonable. What is the use case?

Comment: eg i download a library of 2 different versions but they have the same function names etc...in some scenario, i first use the older version but if certain conditions occur, it would be necessary to overwrite the old version with the newer version....there's always a use case to everything my friend

Comment: Sounds like a bad place to be in to begin with.

Comment: These may help http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: eg. the older version already used in lots of areas in the project so doing a full upgrade is costly - but a feature of the new version desirable in one place so you have 2 versions of the same library that you want to use

Comment: @MarkBaker but then don't you need to modify the source code of the library in everywhere the name is used to take into account the namespace

Comment: @pillarOfLight you're assuming you can call functions from old & new files interleaved without any issues. Unless you have verified this to be true, my experience is that this is rarely correct: often as libs evolve so do their data structures and requirements.

Comment: @rivimey to the contrary, it's because as libs evolve their data structures etc change that I need to do this....essentially, at first I need to load the old version with all its data structures, functions etc, perform some operations, and on some cases I need to unload the old version with all of its data structures etc and then load the new version with their data structures etc without incurring any error

Comment: good question though, it is not that strange to have the same function names in 2 different files. As someone mentioned above however the right way to deal with this is namespaces and classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer: don't do that.

Try to work with the original author to include the functions you need into a patched version of the old code and then use that patched version everywhere.

If you can't do that, find out how big a job it would actually be to update all the code to new version. Start with white-box analysis: see what's changed in terms of interfaces, data structures et al. Then examine the calling code to see whether the caller cares about any of the things that have changed.

If you can't even do that, use namespacing or some other form of wrapping so that you can include both libs. However, make sure any initialisaton or setup is done on both libs!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do, is to include the required (sets) of files based on conditional clauses, instead of trying to "unrequire".

So:

```
if($flag_use_oldver)
{
  include("oldver.php");
}
else
{
 include("newver.php");
}
```

If you want a more sophisticated solution, of course you could try to have a wrapper class hierarchy that will extend/override as required, but I think that is a bit over-engineering for a pretty straightforward problem statement.

Comment: well heres the thing in my use case, in order to know that I need to include the newversion, i need to have included the old version since essentially if something in the old version failed, then do the one in the newversion

Comment: @pillarOfLight that is a bit of a complicated use case :) One thing you could try is include the oldver as normal. For the newver, create a handler wrapper and do not include it anywhere. If the oldver fails, then do a curl call to the newver wrapper, which will in turn call the newver and do the required processing...

Comment: Maybe add a version number in your code, and check with a conditional statement if it's the latest. I've seen something similar in the past, but can't remember where I saw it. @pillarOfLight

Comment: @Fred-ii- it seems like the problem the OP is having is like, s/he wants to include and execute oldver, then evaluate its results, if not ok then include and execute newver. However seems like newver and oldver has the same function names. Do you mean the version number in the code suggests which version to run?

Comment: *"Do you mean the version number in the code suggests which version to run?"* - Yes, I've seen it done before, but for the life of me, can't remember where I saw it. I usually place stuff like that in my bookmarks, but I can't find a reference to it in them. @raidenace

Comment: @pillarOfLight: If you have namespace support how about you include a the second file in another file that is namespaced by you?

Comment: @UndefinedVariable note that the libraries themselves are already using namespaces...theres a whole bunch of namespace and use statements in the libraries, and it's the exact same root name in both versions...how would you reconcile that...I tried using SplClassLoader to overwrite the namespace with the second library but since the older version is already included when it runs it ends up using the old version even though the current namespace points to the new version